# Re- Print Title when Group Changes

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to Build a report that the title band would reprint when my group changes but am unable to figure out how to do this.

On other reports I have been able to do this by moving the Title into the Page header and this worked fine when a Group is only one page but now I have a 3 page group (in this case it should only print on the first page of the 3) .

The ***Print when Group Changes*** option doesn't seem to work as I would assume it should( at least not in the pager header or column header).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a posing for almost the same thing,  here was there suggestion:  [Jasper Reports - Print when group changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715972/jasper-reports-print-when-group-changes)

---

Instead of 'print when group changes' I have used

> $V{yourGroupName_COUNT}==1

in 
**print when** option so that the element prints only once in for a group

---

This Worked but in the page header i was not getting a count of 1 on my group
so being that i has also set the **Reset Page Number** and **Start on new page** options i was able to set the **print when** option on my elements that i want only printed on the first page to

> $V{PAGE_NUMBER} ==1

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the purpose of the `printWhenGroupChanges` attribute. It is only relevant when used in conjunction with `isPrintRepeatedValues`. When you have chosen to hide repeating values in a report, it allows you to set an exception to the rule; The repeated value will hidden *except* at the start of the next group. Because it relates to values repeating in the dataset, it will not have an effect on the page header (as you have already found).

The correct approach here is to use a group header. Put the content you want repeated into a `groupHeader` section for the relevant group.

From the JasperReports Ultimate Guide :

> GROUP HEADER
>   This section marks the start of a new group in the resulting document. It is inserted in 
>   the document every time the value of the group expression changes during the iteration 
>   through the data source.

Comment: you are correct i had misunderstood the **printWhenGroupChanges**. I had tried putting it in the group header but the problem with that was the **Column header** band prints above the **group header** band. so to get the report to process as : title, column header,detail (in that order) with a **Column header** on every page and a Title on the first page of each group.  I have posted How i was able to get this done as an answer.